# Extract CloudFoundry UAAC Access Token in Ansible/Shell

Tags: ansible, cloud-foundry

Following documentation here:
https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-10/customizing/ops-man-api.html

After running:

```
$ uaac target https://OPS-MAN-FQDN/uaa
$ uaac token owner get [options]
$ uaac contexts
```

I get my context with `access_token` field set (which is also stored in `~/.uaac.yml`)

How can I programmatically extract the `access_token` from `uaac context` (and if not from the `~/.uaac.yml`) with substring tools such as awk, gawk, etc.

I am trying to do this in ansible, but shell would work just fine.

In case you are wondering, the output of `uaac context` in stdout is:

```
[2]*[https://OPS-MAN-FQDN/uaa]
  skip_ssl_validation: true

  [0]*[USERNAME]
      user_id: USERID
      client_id: CLIENTID
      access_token: ACCES_TOKEN
      token_type: bearer
      refresh_token: REFRESHTOKEN
      expires_in: 43199
      scope: opsman.admin scim.me opsman.user uaa.admin clients.admin
      jti: JTI VALUE
```

Comment: If you can install a tool, `rq` is an option for reading `.uaac.yml` very easily: https://github.com/dflemstr/rq.  If not, could you use inline python (`python -c 'cmd'` or `ruby -e 'cmd'`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use `grep` it is as simple as:

```
uaac context | grep -Po '(?<=access_token: ).*'
```

which prints the access token.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. As you mentioned in the comments, I was more looking for a tool like rq so that I can extract the variables structurally. But I gave up due to time limitations and used a similar command. This to be exact: - name: Extracting UAAC access_token
  shell: "uaac context YOUREMAIL | grep -o -P '(?<=access_token:\ ).*(?=)'"
  register: context

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Ansible Command that utilized Fabian's solution:

```
- name: Extracting UAAC access_token
  shell: "uaac context YOUREMAIL | grep -o -P '(?<=access_token:\ ).*(?=)'"
  register: context
```